# Using Sequel to convert the result of array_agg into hash or array

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have a complicated SQL which I run with `DB[sql]`. One of the columns is the result of `array_agg` applied to `row` (like this: `array_agg(row(description, amount)::my_type)`) and what I get from `DB` is a string as follows:

```
"{\"(aaaa,11111111.0000000000)\",\"(bbbbb,22222222.0000000000)\",\"(vvvvvv,33333333.0000000000)\"}"
```

I have Sequel on my project and I am aware of the `pg_array` and `pg_row` extensions but I  haven't found a way of converting this string to a hash or array without using something dirty such as:

```
raw = "{\"(aaaa,11111111.0000000000)\",\"(bbbbb,22222222.0000000000)\",\"(vvvvvv,33333333.0000000000)\"}"
Hash[raw.delete('"(){}').split(',').each_slice(2).to_a].each do ... end
```

Is it possible to convert this string to hash or array using Sequel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pg_row and pg_array extensions and have the result be returned as an array of hashes (or custom objects).  Check the documentation for those extensions:

http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_row_rb.html
http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_array_rb.html

This may be as simple as:

```
DB.extension :pg_array, :pg_row
DB.register_row_type(:my_type)
```